# I was doing some moving around in SVN, and copying files back and forth. Now I can't use it

Tags: linux, svn, unix, file

I deleted files in my SVN, and dragged new files into it over WINSCP.

Now, I try to add all the files and commit, but it won't let me.

```
$ svn add *
svn: '.' is not a working copy
svn: Can't open file '.svn/entries': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Uh oh, did you clobber your .svn directory?

Comment: Something like that. What did I do wrong? I just want to have the current files inside my directory.

Comment: probably removed .svn by accident.  Take your tree and copy the source files over a brand new tree, and see if the diffs make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just removed the .svn directory, or moved with hidden files not shown and forgot to move it. Take better care next time ;)

To fix the problem, checking out a new working directory and copying your changed files over it should probably do the trick.